# How do you modify the label of field collection items?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a field collection rendered as a table that contains Username followed by marks in 5 subjects. During form edit, I wanted to modify the title for each 5 marks entered as the subject name corresponding to the semester selected in the node form containing the field collection items. Each semester contains list of subject names. The number of subjects per semester is fixed.

I created a tpl.php file for the form. However setting the value of the #title field using the form array does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Lets see the code

Comment: Thanks. I used an alternate approach to modify the fields by using field templates. Even that didn't work for form. It worked well for node view though.  Finally I decided to alter the field collection table module to allow label changes. I altered the field_collection_table_form_alter method and added semester_subjects array in variables for the field name  and modified the theme_field_collection_table_multiple_value_fields method to change the header for the field collection field.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php -->
  
  function field_collection_table_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
    foreach (field_info_instances($form['#entity_type'], $form['#bundle']) as $field_name => $instance) {  
    if (isset($form[$field_name]) && $instance['widget']['type'] == 'field_collection_table') {  
      $language = $form[$field_name]['#language'];  
      $semester_tid = $form['field_external_exam_semester'][$language]['#default_value'][0];  
      $form[$field_name][$language]['#semester_subjects']= jicustom_semester_subjects($semester_tid);  
    }  
  }